# Limit loop with condition

Tags: python, loops

I have a list of let's say 500,000 entries, with each being a tuple such as `(val1, val2)`.

Currently, I am looping through the list and inside the loop, I have a condition such as:

```
if val2 == someval:
    do_something()
    break
```

However, I was wondering if there was a faster way to loop through elements on a certain condition, such as only looping through items where `val2 == someval`, rather than the entire list THEN doing the check.

Comment: Not unless your list is sorted by `val2`.

Comment: @Pat841: most of the questions you've asked on SO lack an accepted answer — you should work on that.

Answer (score 1):

What about taking it from the other side:

```
if someval in lst:
  my_action(somewal)
```

The test of somewal membership in lst also requires a loop, but this runs in more optimized code in C, so it might be faster.

```
In [49]: x = 3

In [50]: %timeit x in [1, 2, 3]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 53.8 ns per loop

In [51]: %timeit x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 3
10000000 loops, best of 3: 85.5 ns per loop

In [52]: x = 1

In [53]: %timeit x in [1, 2, 3]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 38.5 ns per loop

In [54]: %timeit x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 3
10000000 loops, best of 3: 38.4 ns per loop
```

Here you can see, that for numbers, which are "soon" in the test, the time difference is neglectable, but for "later on" it is faster to test membership.

More realistic measurements case: having range of 500000 numbers, testing presence of a number in the middle:

```
In [64] lst = range(500000)

In [65]: %%timeit
250000 in lst
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.66 ms per loop

In [66]: %%timeit
for i in lst:
  if i == 250000:
    break
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 6.6 ms per loop
```

The time needed drops down to 40% with membership test `x in lst`

Comment: Are you saing `x in [1, 2, 3]` is faster than `x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 3`?

Comment: OK, didn't know it even worked for such small sets; I think on PyPy, it's a different story though.

Comment: @ErikAllik The answer to PyPy performance in this case is hidden behind favourite optimization phrase "measure it".

Comment: Btw this will only provide a constant improvement, and assuming he has multiple `==` and only `==`. And even if he has, if his code takes 60 seconds to run and he wants to get down to 5, he can't benefit from this optimizations.

Comment: And... I'm installing PyPy as we speak (for some reason, it has disappeared from my computer :)) — hmm, surprising; `x in [1,2,3]` is much faster even on PyPy! Not sure how that can be...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure there is a faster way. As I see it, you have to first find "val2" in the list, which in my experience requires a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This code for example will iterate the loop and will print val1
only if val2 == someval.

```
for val1, val2 in some_list:
    if val2 != someval:
        continue
    print val1
```

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be asking two different questions. One in which the first time you see something equal to someval you break, the other where you only look through those that are equal to someval. For the latter, i.e.:

"However, I was wondering if there was a faster way to loop through elements on a certain condition, such as only looping through items where val2 == someval, rather than the entire list THEN doing the check."

You can do:

```
for i in filter(lambda t: t[1] == someval, val_list):
    stuff
```

Or via list comprehension:

```
for i in [x for x in val_list if x[1] == someval]:
    stuff
```

My guess is that one of these is faster.

Comment: Your guess is wrong. Always benchmark before making such random claims; IPython has a convenient `timeit` command which you can use to compare 2 or more code snippets.

Answer (score -1):

You have to "see" all the elements in the list to able to decide if at any point `val2 == someval` and your list isn't sorted on the second value in the tuple, so looping over all the elements can't be avoided.

However, you can make sure the method you use to loop over the list is as efficient as possible. For instance, instead of using a [`for statement`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), you *may* use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter out the values that satisfy `val2 == someval` and then `do something` if the returned list isn't empty. I say "*may*" because it really depends on the distribution of your data; whether it's useful to you to have all values for which `val2 == someval` holds true and performing some action etc.

If you're using Python 3.x then ["list comprehensions and generator expressions in Python 3 are actually faster than they were in Python 2"](http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html).

Comment: list comprehensions will *not* make this any faster; in fact they'll be much worse because they walk through all the items in the list and then create another list. A generator expression would be OK but *not* any faster than a `for` loop.

Comment: List comprehensions will be marginally faster. It's true that they will create a new list and they have to iterate through the whole initial list but they will marginally out-perform a `for statement`.

Comment: There is no way they can outperform a `for` loop if you don't need to generate a new list during the loop. Feel free to convince me otherwise with some benchmark examples though.

Comment: I'll benchmark a couple of examples tomorrow. I'm definitely not saying it will always be faster. I am merely suggesting that it may be faster in some circumstances depending on the distribution of data etc. so it's something to consider (as opposed to "you have to 100% use list comprehensions")

Comment: I don't see how data distribution can affect this at all. But I'm looking forward to the benchmarks.

Answer (score -1):

1. there is no way to avoid the loop or the `if`; the answers suggesting there is a faster way are mistaken; `filter` and list comprehensions will *not* improve matters a single bit; in fact, unless you use generator expressions (which are lazily evaluated), comprehensions (as well as `filter`) will make this (potentially much) slower and memory consuming. And generator expressions will not improve the performance either.
2. there is no way to make it faster other than rewriting in a language such as C or Java or using PyPy or Cython. `for x in ...: if x ...: do_smth()` is already the fastest possible way. Of course depending on your data, you can actually build the data structure (that has 500 000 items) in a way that is always sorted, so you could potentially have to loop over only the beginning of the list. Or possibly collecting the items satisfying a certain condition into a separate list/set/whatnot, which will yield very good results later by completely avoiding the filtering and a full loop iteration.